# Permute elements of array according to another one, without making a copy

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, permutation

Consider an array. What is a good way to permute its elements according to another array that gives the new positions of elements (without making a copy of the array first)?

For example

```
int a[]={37,43,5,10}; //array to permute
int b[]={3,1,4,2};  //new position of each element
```

so a should become

```
{43,10,37,5}
```

I naturally thought about making a copy of a and then re allocate its element in the new positions. But is there a way to do it without making a copy of the array a (i.e. a more simple way)?

**Note**:  If possible the way to do it should not use particular C++ headers but only `<iostream>`

Comment: That seems backwards and off by one..

Comment: @RickAstley You're thinking the opposite way - 5 is the 3rd element of the first array, then 37 which is the first, then 10 the 4th and 43 the 2nd. You basically wants `a[b - 1]`, if such notation was allowed in C++.

Comment: @Holt Ah I see, mixed it up there.

Answer (score 10):

It can be done in O(n) time with O(1) extra memory, by handling the cycles of the permutation array one at a time.

**Note**: this approach is more complicated than needed for this particular setting (`a` and `b` are both int arrays), but it has some benefits:

- it can handle arbitrary datatypes (*e.g.* the permuted array `a` can be an array of strings).
- it can retain the original values in `b`, the permutation array.

---

Consider the initial example:

```
int a[] = {37, 43, 5, 10};  // array to permute
int b[] = { 3,  1, 4,  2};  // new position of each element
```

The array `b` indicates that we want to make the following chain of assignments:

`a[1] <-- a[3] <-- a[4] <-- a[2] <-- a[1]`.

The problem is that at the last assignment, we don't anymore have access to `a[1]` (it has already been replaced to `a[3]`).

However, the original value of the starting element can be saved in an auxiliary variable, so that we use it when we close the cycle (it is guaranteed that when we close the cycle we will reach precisely the element that we have started from - otherwise some element would be reachable in multiple ways, *i.e.* we would have b[i] = b[j]), for some i != j).

---

In general, the permutation may contain multiple cycles. After a cycle is processed, we need to start with an element that had not yet been updated (*i.e.* it was not part of a cycle processed so far).

Thus, we need to know which elements were not processed so far.

A possible approach is to temporarily modify the permutation vector `b` in order to keep track of which elements were updated, *e.g.* negating the value at the corresponding position in `b` when updating an element in `a`. This has the advantage that at the end, we can iterate through all elements of `b` and restore the initial values (by negating all of them again).

---

Below is an implementation of the previous ideas.

```
int main() {
    int a[] = {11, 22, 33, 44};
    int b[] = { 2,  1,  4,  3};
    int aux, crtIdx, nxtIdx;

    int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // check whether the i'th element
        // was already processed
        if (b[i] < 0) {
            continue;
        }

        // start processing of a new cycle;
        // backup the first value to aux
        aux = a[i];
        crtIdx = i;
        nxtIdx = b[i] - 1;

        // advance along the cycle until we reach 
        // again the first element 
        while (nxtIdx != i) {
            a[crtIdx] = a[nxtIdx];

            // use the b array to mark that the 
            // element at crtIdx was updated
            b[crtIdx] = -b[crtIdx];

            crtIdx = nxtIdx;
            nxtIdx = b[nxtIdx] - 1;
        }

        // finalize the cycle using the aux variable
        a[crtIdx] = aux;
        b[crtIdx] = -b[crtIdx];
    }

    // restore the original values of b[i]
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        b[i] = -b[i];
    }
}
```

Note: although the code contains two nested loops, the time complexity is O(n). This can be seen by considering the fact that each element is updated exactly once (the outer loop is immediately continued if we reach an element that was already processed).

---

I'll show here the main steps performed by the algorithm, using this example:

```
a = {11, 22, 33, 44}
b = { 2,  1,  4,  3}
```

**Step 1.**
We look at the first element (please see the outer `for` loop over `i` from the code). The first element is not part of an already processed cycle, thus we start the processing of a new cycle. We do so by storing in `aux` the initial value of this element.

```
a = {11, 22, 33, 44}
b = { 2,  1,  4,  3}
aux = 11
```

**Step 2.**
We go along this cycle, update elements, mark them as updated (by negating the corresponding element in the `b` array), until we reach again the first element.

```
a = {22, 22, 33, 44}
b = {-2,  1,  4,  3}
aux = 11
```

**Step 3.**
We reached again the first element of the cycle, and need its initial value in order to update the last element of the cycle. This is where we use the auxiliary variable. In this way, the first cycle is completely processed.

```
a = {22, 11, 33, 44}
b = {-2, -1,  4,  3}
aux = 11
```

**Step 4.**
We continue the outer loop (the `for` over `i`). We see that the second element was already processed (because `b[1]` is negative), thus we don't start a new cycle here. We continue, and start a new cycle at the third element (which was not yet processed).

Now we can *reuse* the same `aux` variable to backup the first element of this cycle (we no longer need to hold the value from the first cycle, because that cycle was completely resolved).

```
a = {22, 11, 33, 44}
b = {-2, -1,  4,  3}
aux = 33
```

**Step 5.**
The processing of the second cycle is performed in a similar manner described in the previous steps, resulting in the end in this:

```
a = {22, 11, 44, 33}
b = {-2, -1, -4, -3}
aux = 33
```

**Step 6.**
The loop over `i` continues, and no un-processed element is found.
Now, that we know that all elements were processed, we can negate each element in `b` in order to restore the original values.

```
a = {22, 11, 44, 33}
b = { 2,  1,  4,  3}
```

Comment: Are you sure this works in all cases? If his `b` array is `[3,4,1,2]`, then don't you have to put two numbers in temporary storage?

Comment: @Jimmischel indeed, that permitation has two cycles, but the cycles are handled one at a time (and after finishing the processing of a cycle, the stored value is no longer needed and the same auxiliary variabile can be reused), thus still a single auxiliary variable will be needed.

Comment: I think I'll have to draw a picture. Or take out my playing cards and model this. I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @JimMischel :-) I will add a C/C++ implementation (but most likely tomorrow) -- I'll send another reply here after I'll have done that. Thank you for the interest in this method!

Comment: @JimMischel I've added more details to my answer.

Comment: If you would use `~` to mark proceed indecies instead of `-`, you could enumerate permutation from zero.

Comment: @qwertyman Fantastic answer. I especially liked the explanation on the need to store the `aux` variable of the `i`'th value which needs to be replaced when we find the last element that loops back to `i` (as the value `i` would have been replaced by the first element that its permutation points to).

Answer (score 6):

The simplest answer is to copy `a` into `b`, destroying b as you go:

```
for (i = 0; i < B_SIZE; ++i):
    b[i] = a[b[i] - 1];
```

Then, if you must, just copy `b` back to `a`:

```
for (i = 0; i < B_SIZE; ++i):
    a[i] = b[i];
```

Since `a` and `b` are both int arrays, you're not using up any excess memory in doing so.  You end with the correct values in `a`, without using  any more memory than what was given to you. This isn't maximally efficient (though it is O(n)), but it is simplest to understand.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to avoid copying an array, it generally means limiting yourself to swaps.

If we use swaps to sort `b[]`, and use the same swaps for `a[]`, then `a[]` will end up permuted according to the values of `b[]`.

I'm going to step through the algorithm below.  For simplicity, I start array counting at 1, although in C arrays count starting at 0.  You'll have to adjust for that in your code.

```
a[]={37, 43, 5, 10} //array to permute
b[]={3, 1, 4, 2}  //new position of each element

i = 1; b[i] = 3
swap(a[1], a[3]); a[] = {5, 43, 37, 10}
swap(b[1], b[3]); b[] = {4, 1, 3, 2}

i = 1; b[i] = 4
swap(a[1], a[4]); a[] = {10, 43, 37, 5}
swap(b[1], b[4]); b[] = {2, 1, 3, 4}

i = 1; b[i] = 2
swap(a[1], a[2]); a[] = {43, 10, 37, 5}
swap(b[1], b[2]); b[] = {1, 2, 3, 4}

i = 1; b[i] = 1
++i

i = 2; b[i] = 2
++i

i = 3; b[i] = 3
++i

i = 4; b[i] = 4
++i

i = 5; i > 4
DONE
```

Note how we step through `b[]` at the end there.  Consider the case that `b[]={2, 1, 4, 3}`

```
a[] = {37, 43, 5, 10}
b[] = {2, 1, 4, 3}

i = 1; b[i] = 2
swap(a[1], a[2]); a[] = {43, 37, 5, 10}
swap(b[1], b[2]); b[] = {1, 2, 4, 3}

i = 1; b[i] = 1
++i

i = 2; b[i] = 2
++i

i = 3; b[i] = 4
swap(a[3], a[4]); a[] = {43, 37, 10, 5}
swap(b[3], b[4]); b[] = {1, 2, 3, 4}

i = 3; b[i] = 3
++i

i = 4; b[i] = 4
++i

i = 5; i > 4
DONE
```

With every swap, one element of the array ends up in the correct position, meaning we perform at most N swaps.